# Erro ao popular Google Chart

Tags: jquery, json, google-charts

Aparece o seguinte erro

> Invalid data table format: column #0 must be of type 'string'.

Neste momento tenho o retorno em json desta forma:

```
[{"Field":"OrderTask","Old":"1","New":"2","Modified":"2016-12-08 11:16:27"},
{"Field":"Status","Old":"1","New":"4","Modified":"2016-12-08 13:43:51"}]
```

E tenho o seguinte código do Google Chart:

```
$("#dataTables-tasks tbody").on("click", "tr", function(){

    var idTask = $(this).find('td.id-task').html();
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


     function drawChart() {
       var jsonData = $.ajax({
       url: "../connect/post/select.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data:'numIdTask='+idTask
     }).responseText;

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      var options = {
        width: 550,
        height: 400,
        gantt: {
          trackHeight: 30
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
});
```

Comment: Você não definiu o tipo de cada coluna do seu JSON, tem que definir antes de passar os dados para o DataTable. Veja aqui na API do [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_preparing_data)

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse método também: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?csw=1#DataTable_toJSON

Comment: Pior que defini, tirei depois de seguir esta parte[Populating Data Using Server-Side Code][1]


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example#getdataphp-file

Comment: No seu JSON que está vindo do server, tá definido nesse formato que você mandou nesse link? Verifique se existe a _key_ chamada _type_. Pois é isso que o erro está informando.